# Getting error when deploying Laravel code

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

trying to deploy locally first, then to Heroku code following tutorial provided by class professor. Followed video to the T but his deploys and mine doesn't. I am code-dumb so please be as basic as possible. https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1583&v=8NOslcDSIoI

Using Laravel with PhpStorm.

```
Could not find resource 'views/layouts.html.php' in any resource paths.(searched: C:\Users\{MY NAME}\PhpstormProjects\is601webpage\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Handler/../Resources)
(1/1) RuntimeException
Could not find resource 'views/layouts.html.php' in any resource paths.(searched: C:\Users\{MY NAME}\PhpstormProjects\is601webpage\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Handler/../Resources)

in PrettyPageHandler.php line 621
at PrettyPageHandler->getResource('views/layouts.html.php')
in PrettyPageHandler.php line 170
at PrettyPageHandler->handle(object(ErrorException))
in Run.php line 320
at Run->handleException(object(ErrorException))
in Handler.php line 343
at Handler->renderExceptionWithWhoops(object(ErrorException))
in Handler.php line 322
at Handler->renderExceptionContent(object(ErrorException))
in Handler.php line 306
at Handler->convertExceptionToResponse(object(ErrorException))
in Handler.php line 285
```

Comment: Please show the controller action that is attempting to return the layouts.html.php view.

Answer (score 1):

File name should be layouts.blade.php.